# How to subtract two dataframe column in dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dask

I have two dataframes like df1, df2.
In df1 i have 4 columns (A,B,C,D) and two rows,
In df2 i have 4 columns (A,B,C,D) and two rows.
Now I want to subtract the two dataframe LIKE df1['A'] - df2['A'] and so on. But I don't know how to do it.

df1-

[image: dataframe 1]

df2 -

[image: dataframe 2]

Comment: Hello, please attach a minimum reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Please take the time to format your question so that it isn't so hard to read. If you expect someone to put in the effort to help solve your problem, you can put in the effort to make the question easily readable.

Comment: I understands. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the subtraction but keep in mind the indexes, for example, let's say I have `df1` and `df2` with same columns but different index:

```
df1 = dd.from_array(np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])

df2 = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4),
    columns=['A','B','C','D'],
    index=[1, 2]
), npartitions=1)
```

Then:

```
(df1 - df2).compute()

#       A       B       C       D
# 0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
# 1     4.0     4.0     4.0     4.0
# 2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

On the other hand, let's match index from df2 to df1 and subtract

```
df2 = df2.assign(idx=1)
df2 = df2.set_index(df2.idx.cumsum() - 1)
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['idx'])

(df1 - df2).compute()


#       A   B   C   D
# 0     0   0   0   0
# 1     0   0   0   0
```